# How to determine current stream type in c++?

Tags: c++

I am using a template in c++, and I am passing a stream object as an templated argument. How to know the current stream type at run time?

Comment: Show the code and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are a compile-time construction, so there's nothing to do "at runtime". But that's even better. Probably the most idiomatic way is to use `char_traits`:

```
template <typename TChar, typename Traits>
void foo(std::basic_ostream<TChar, Traits> & o)
{
  // use `Traits` in here
  // e.g. Traits::char_type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Attempt to dynamic_cast<> to possible stream types that you're interested in, and see which ones succeed
- Use typeid and compare to known types
- Require the user of the template to pass an additional parameter saying what the stream type is
- Provide template specialisations for the specific stream types which need different handling

However, all of these are limiting - they all require you to know about different stream types, and if any of them require special handling within your templated class you may later find another one needs to be added, and another... ideally a template should work more generally than that.

Since stream classes in the standard library all derive from a common ancestor, the other option is to not use a template but accept a pointer or reference to the ancestor type at the level providing the features you need and rely on polymorphism. Again, this affords the possibility of specialising for particular types using overloading if you need to.

Comment: Some compilers also have a `typeid` keyword that might be used.

Comment: Other way around: `typeid` is standard, `typeof` is an extension. I can't tell whether or not Joachim spotted that and was being facetious...